# Kubernetes Ingress NGINX Rewrite - How to Support Multiple Path Patterns for Different Domains

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

The goal is to support the following two use cases:

1. Our organization has one shared domain, `shared.domain.com`, so each service needs to have a unique path. For example, for our service, `myservice`, we choose `/myservice`. So we want a request to `shared.domain.com/myservice/users` to be rewritten and routed to our service with the path `/user`.
2. We also have a service-specific domain, `myservice.domain.com`. In this case, we don't need a rewrite, per se: a request to `myservice.domain.com/users` should be passed through to our service with the path `/user`. However, since we need a rewrite to satisfy #1 above, we need to work within the "framework" of a rewrite for this use case as well.

We're using a Kubernetes Ingress NGINX rewrite (`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target`). Use case #1 is working fine. However, we can't figure out how to get #2 working.

For now we had to use the same path for both domains which is not ideal because it's not backwards compatible for anyone who was calling `myservice.domain.com/users`. Now they have to call `myservice.domain.com/myservice/users`. We could make a code change to make this backwards compatible for our callers, but again that's not ideal.

Here's our configuration:

```yaml
# ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: $APP_NAME
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: 'https'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from: "http://"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to: "https://"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: shared.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /myservice(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: $APP_NAME
              servicePort: http
    - host: myservice.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "(/|$)(.*)" # Doesn't work
            backend:
              serviceName: $APP_NAME
              servicePort: http
```

We used these docs as a reference: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this regex in the path for the `myservice.domain.com`:

`/*(/|$)(.*)`

Also you're using `v1beta1` api which is already depricated and will be unavailable soon:

> Warning: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.19+,
> unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress

Below `ingress.yaml` written using `v1` with correct regex for `myservice.domain.com`:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: $APP_NAME
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: 'https'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from: "http://"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to: "https://"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: shared.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /myservice(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: $APP_NAME
                port:
                  number: 80
    - host: myservice.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: $APP_NAME
                port:
                  number: 80
```